# Laravel get model with relation's pivot condition

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I need to get all `appeals`, that have `appeal_stage.expiration_date` less than `NOW()`.

[image]

Now I have following solution:

```
public function scopeExpired($query) {
    $query->join('appeal_stage', 'appeals.id', 'appeal_stage.appeal_id')
        ->where('appeal_stage.expiration_date', '<=', new Expression('NOW()'));
}
```

but resulted model dump shows that joined table is recognized as pivot table:
[image]

So, I want to ask - Is there some more convenient way to perform this request?
My suggestions is use `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot` somehow, bu I do not quiet understand, how Pivot can be used here.

**UPD 1**

Models has next relations:

```
public function stages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Stage::class)->withPivot('prolongated_count', 'expiration_date')->withTimestamps();
}

public function appeals() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Appeal::class);
}
```

Comment: Your table `appeal_stage` is a pivot table. I would try using Eloquent relationships and the `wherePivot()` method instead of manually joining them in your scope method.

Comment: `wherePivot()` will filter `Stage` by condition, not `Appeal`.

Comment: how you have defined your relationships in models? please share your models

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$appeal->stages()->wherePivot('expiration_date', '<', $now)->get()
```

Comment: Nope, wherePivot will apply to stages, not to appeal.

Comment: Update the appeals relationship to 

public function appeals() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Appeal::class)->withPivot('prolongated_count', 'expiration_date')->withTimestamps();
}

Comment: Do you mean - in Stage model?

Comment: I've read your question again and as you are looking for appeals, I don't understand why the answer provided doesn't work.    When you say 'wherePivot will apply to stages, not to appeal', what do you mean?  What do you actually see when you are looping through appeals and using the above?

Comment: WherePivot method applies they condition to Stages when getting Stages through relation.

Answer (score 2):

You should create relationship in `appeal` model

```
public function stages()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Stage::class,'appeal_stage','appeal_id','stage_id')->wherePivot('expiration_date','<',Carbon::now())->withTimestamps();
}
```

In belongs To Many relationship second argument is your `Pivot` table name

Comment: And how I should get pivot data?

Comment: You should add withPivot() method inside the relationship and pass field name in that method

Comment: And what I should do if I don't need `expiration_date` condition everywhere? Separate relation?

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: I want to only get Appeals with condition from pivot table, without stages.